# How to use getCellMeta in afterChange at Handsontable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hook, handsontable

I'm using **[handsontable](https://handsontable.com/)** js plugin. I want to use **[getCellMeta](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.0.0/Core.html#getCellMeta)** function in **[afterChange](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.0.0/Hooks.html#event:afterChange)** hook but not working.
I when use function out afterChange hook, function is working. But not working in afterChange hook.

```
var container = document.getElementById('t1'),
  options = document.querySelectorAll('.options input'),
  table,
  hot; 

hot = new Handsontable(container, {    
  autoWrapRow: true,
  startRows: 81,
  startCols: 206,
  autoColumnSize : true,  
  stretchH: 'all', 
  afterChange : function(change,source) { 
      if (source === 'loadData') {
        return;
      }   
      var test = this.getCellMeta(change[0],change[1]); // not working, not return "id" meta
      console.log(test);  
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'path',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (res) { 
    var data = [], row, pc = 0; 
    for (var i = 0, ilen =  hot.countRows(); i < ilen; i++)
    {
      row = []; 
      for (var ii = 0; ii<hot.countCols(); ii++)
      {   
        hot.setCellMeta(i,ii,'id',res[pc].id);
        row[ii] =   res[pc].price;
        if(pc < (res.length-1)) {

        pc++;
        }
      } 
      data[i] = row;
    }  
    hot.loadData(data);
  }
}); 

var test = this.getCellMeta(0,0); // is working, return "id" meta
console.log(test);
```

**Output console log i tried out afterChange;**
[image]

**Output console log use in afterChange;**
[image]

How to get cell meta after change?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this plugin but the documentation only shows beforeGetCellMeta and afterGetCellMeta ; where does the getCellMeta come from?

Comment: [link](https://image.prntscr.com/image/pSN__mN-RpCONgy_320krA.png) @kshikama

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, there's just a small mistake in your callback: the [doc for `afterChange`](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.0.0/Hooks.html#event:afterChange) specifies that first argument (`changes`) of the callback is:

> a 2D array containing information about each of the edited cells
>   `[[row, prop, oldVal, newVal], ...]`.

So, 2 important details:

- To get the "meta" of row/col of affected cell (assuming there is just one), you need to call `hot.getCellMeta(change[0][0],change[0][1])` for example
- On `hot` and not `this` because the `afterChange` callback function is invoked from a different context (ie on a different object), so `this` is not the right target for the call, see [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/6730571)

Example that reads the whole array of changes:

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  /* rest of init... */
  afterChange : function(changes,source) {
      console.log("Changes:", changes, source);
      if (changes) {
          changes.forEach(function(change) {
              var test = hot.getCellMeta(change[0],change[1]);
              console.log(test.id, test); // 'id' is the property you've added earlier with setMeta         
          });
      }
  }
});
```

See [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szmchpst/), open JS console, make any change(s) in the table.

Comment: Also, can't really call `this.getCellMeta(change[0][0],change[0][1])` because of context change. Need to reference hansontable object by name: `hot.getCellMeta(change[0],change[1]);`

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I did in the complete example, but I left `this` in the one-liner. Will edit, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps, add a note about the context change to your answer as well, because this is something that gets everyone: people assume that `this` inside their `Handsontable(...)` definition refers to handsontable object, but it doesn't, since Handsontable switches context on you for the `afterChange` call.

Comment: Better now? I was not planning on grooming this answer too much, as it was only resolving a simple mistake (and, yes, a known problem with `this` that already has an answer, so I linked to it). Feel free to edit :)